# Node.js folder is m.i.a

Tags: node.js, atom-editor

I'm trying to use node.js in atom, but I can't seem to find the nodejs folder even though I've downloaded node.js. I can find a node executable but no folder to start a project with.  I've shown hidden files, and relaunched finder, and still no luck.Can anyone advise me on what to do?

Comment: what are you trying to do? Your question is a bit unclear. If you want to run a project with Node, you have to create the project or folder naming it whatever you want and then you run the `node` command to start that specific `.js` file

Comment: @MikeDiglio Sorry about that I'm pretty new to programming and don't have a complete grasp on anything really. But do I just make a folder and name it "anything.js" and then run the node command in terminal? Im on a mac. Also whats the full node command? Thanks homie

Comment: The folder you make would be the name of your project "MyProject" or whatever you want. Inside that folder, you would need to make an `app.js` file and then configure it to start. You would then run, from terminal, `node app.js` - I suggest checking this link out for how to get started - https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/

Comment: Ok how do I make the file? I understand the rest I think.

Comment: you can do it directly in atom, or by using terminal `touch app.js` - this will create the app.js file at current working directory

Comment: Ok I got everything working except when I go to localhost it says it couldn't be reached. Terminal didn't give an error or anything when I ran it